# What was the purpose and history of the C64's special keys?

Tags: history, commodore-64, keyboards

I never had a Commodore 64 but I've always been curious what the purpose and history of some of the special keys were. In particular:

- <kbd>C=</kbd>
- <kbd>Run/Stop</kbd>
- <kbd>Clr/Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Restore</kbd>

I'm mostly used to the standard ASCII keyboards from the era and whenever I had sat in front of a Commodore these keys didn't seem to do much. But to be fair, I believe the <kbd>Run/Stop</kbd> key would break listings and the <kbd>C=</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> key would possibly switch out the character set to allow for lowercase. But were there other uses? How come <kbd>Run/Stop</kbd> can break a program but not start it? What is the <kbd>Restore</kbd> key and why is it so big?

I *think* the same keyboard was used on the other Commodore machines, but memory isn't clear. Are the behaviors consistent?

Comment: To be fair, most software (all not written in BASIC, so "all") did remap the keyboard completely for its own purposes. So, which function was on a certain key depended on the program you were running.

Comment: You CAN use the RUN feature of the RUN/STOP key to load from disc. Type four spaces, "*",8(,1) shift return, shift cursor up, shift RUN. This will launch the 1st program on disc and run it.

Comment: Hmm... I never used that key for that purpose, but I think `down`, `del`, `"*",8` `shift+up` `shift+run` would be fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Background: The Original PET Keyboard and PETSCII

Most of these keys have their roots in the original [Commodore
PET 2001 keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PET_Keyboard.svg):

[image: PET 2001 Keyboard Layout]

The [scanning and conversion was complex](https://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/code/HEAD/tree/techdocs/PET/PETdoc.txt) and seems to have
varied somewhat by ROM version, but eventually a [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII#Character_set) code would
be produced from a keypress. For the original keyboard, typing a key
with a printable character would produce that PETSCII character, and
holding shift would produce the same character code but with the high
bit set (128 added to it) to give the graphic symbol printed on the
shifted portion of the key.

The other keys produced PETSCII control characters very similiar to
ASCII control characters. As you can see from the table at line
551 of [`petdoc.txt`](https://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/code/HEAD/tree/techdocs/PET/PETdoc.txt), these were:

```
    Lower       Shifted     Code
    --------------------------------------------------
    RETURN                  ^M (CR or carriage return)
    RVS         RVS OFF     ^R
    STOP        RUN         ^C (CAN, cancel)
    HOME        CLR         ^S
    CRSR ↓      CRSR ↑      ^Q
    CRSR →      CRSR ←      ^]
    DEL         INST        ^T
```

Using shift with the above keys (excepting <kbd>RETURN</kbd>) would
also set the high bit, just as with the other keys, giving a PETSCII
code in the "high control" area.

#### STOP/RUN and HOME/CLR

The <kbd>STOP/RUN</kbd> and <kbd>HOME/CLR</kbd> keys, along with
<kbd>DEL/INST</kbd>, <kbd>CRSR↓/↑</kbd>, <kbd>CRSR→/←</kbd>, do just
what they did on the PET: they send the appropriate key codes which
are then interpreted by the screen editor or, when embedded into a
BASIC string and printed, perform their action. From BASIC you can
also print the PETSCII code directly with, e.g. `CHR$(19)` or
`CHR$(128+19)` to home the cursor or clear the screen, just as if
you'd pressed or stored the <kbd>HOME/CLR</kbd> key.

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key on the Commodore 64 allows input of the same
characters as all of the unshifted keys above; <kbd>CTRL S</kbd> will
do the same thing as pressing <kbd>HOME</kbd>. However,
<kbd>CTRL SHIFT</kbd> combinations don't work.

The one exception here is <kbd>STOP/RUN</kbd>. Neither its unshifted
(`CHR$(3)`) nor shifted (`CHR$(128+3)`) code does anything when
printed. Additionally, the shifted key does not embed when typing into
a quoted BASIC string and will always type its `LOAD` followed by
`RUN` sequence.

#### The Commodore <kbd>C=</kbd> Key

The VIC-20 removed the numeric keypad that the PET keyboards had,
combining the numeric and punctuation keys on the top row with the
unshifted keystrokes giving numbers and the shifted keystrokes giving
punctuation (`!`, `"`, etc.). They also added colour and assigned
character codes to change the colour of the text. A good guess would
be that this is the reason they added the <kbd>C=</kbd>: it's a second
kind of shift that now allows three PETSCII codes to be produced from
each key rather than just two. This allows all the original graphics
codes still to be produced and adds enough extra keystroke inputs to
cover the new colours as well. The same keyboard and decoding was used
on the C64, with a few extra color codes added.

Thus, while <kbd>SHIFT L</kbd> produced PETSCII code 204 (lower left
box) on both the PET and the C64, <kbd>SHIFT 6</kbd> produced code 182
(right half-box) on the PET but an ampersand `&` on the C64, and to
get that code 182 on the C64 you'd instead use <kbd>C= L</kbd>.

#### The RESTORE Key

As others have pointed out, the new <kbd>RESTORE</kbd> key added on
the VIC-20 isn't actually connected to the keyboard matrix; it's
connected to the CPU's non-maskable interrupt (NMI) line - this connection is routed through a VIA 6520 interface chip on the VIC-20, but it was turned into a direct connection through a minimal filtering circuit on the C-64. This allows
you to send an interrupt that can't be blocked (like RESET) but makes
it easier to have the running code do a "soft reset" when pressed,
which is a reasonable enough idea. The standard ROMs intercept this
and, if the <kbd>STOP/RUN</kbd> is held down while <kbd>RESTORE</kbd>
is pressed, do a soft reset, returning you to a clear screen and BASIC
prompt with memory left intact.

Comment: One small thing: a shift-Return is really different from a normal one. It moves the cursor to the next line, but does not complete an input operation. So in direct mode, it doesn't execute the command you enter. Nor when anwering a Basic INPUT statement.

Comment: @Rhialto Interesting. [I wonder what the point of that is.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14250/7208)

Answer (score 36):

The <kbd>Restore</kbd> key triggered the NMI (non-maskable interrupt) line; to actually have an effect it had to be combined with <kbd>Run/Stop</kbd> - it would soft-reset the machine (via an indirect jump vector that could be overwritten to a custom routine if desired.  This wouldn't reset memory, but would stop even misbehaving programs in most cases.)

<kbd>Run/Stop</kbd> was two keys; unshifted, it was `Stop` and would halt the current action (like listing a program or stop a running BASIC program).  Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Run/Stop</kbd> would be a shortcut for the `LOAD` command.

<kbd>Clr/Home</kbd> was similar.  Unshifted, it moved the cursor to the upper-left corner of the screen.  Shifted (`Clr`) it cleared the screen and moved the cursor to the upper-left.  (If you were in an open quoted string, it would actually insert the control character for these things, so you could have a command in a program that would "print" the `Clr` character, and when you ran the program it would clear the screen.)

The <kbd>C=</kbd> key had a few uses.  One, when combined with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> would switch between uppercase/graphics and lower/uppercase characters.  It was also an alternate `SHIFT` key to access additional characters on the keyboard.  Lastly, <kbd>C=</kbd> plus the numbers 1-8 would allow choices of 8 additional text colors (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and 1-8 are the other 8 colors).

http://sta.c64.org/cbm64petkey.html

Comment: As an aside: I *never* used the `Run` part of Run/Stop on purpose.

Comment: `Shift` + `Run/Stop` executes a `LOAD` before the `RUN`.

Comment: @kolrabi RIGHT.  But it was the tape-style LOAD without any drive specifier...

Comment: The *Restore* key gave an NMI immediately on pressing it. It was the default NMI handling function which checked if Run/Stop was pressed also - and abadoned the request if not. But programs may change that handler and the *Restore* behaviour, too. It wasn't used much, though, because NMIs have even higher priority than the raster IRQ many programs used to control the screen more decently, and pressing *Restore* lead to glitches because of that.

Comment: @Janka: Actually, VIC-20 and C64 Restore keys generated the NMI on *release*.  The C128 seems to have changed the behavior, though.

Comment: Silly thing to do.  Four spaces, "*",8, shift return, shift crsr up, shift RUN would load and then run the 1st item on the disc.  Also, on the SX-64, there was no tape support, do the shift RUN defaulted to the disc drive.

Answer (score 18):

I just want to add to the existing answers that the <kbd>Restore</kbd> key was a weird key.  It was on hardware side already completely independent of all the other keys.  It was attached to the NMI line of the processor, only proxied by a small circuit which let only rising flanks pass.  This circuit sometimes ignored a simple slow press and reacted much more reliably on a series of such flanks in quick succession.  Users could create these when hitting the key quite hard and fast and so letting the key bounce (that usage was typically rather loud and could have inspired the term "hacker" — just kidding).

The <kbd>Stop</kbd> key (which was <kbd>Run</kbd> when used with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, hence it was often mis-called <kbd>Run Stop</kbd>, but in fact a simple press on <kbd>Stop</kbd> stopped a running program if that didn't take care to avoid this behavior) was a key of the normal keyboard matrix.  So the NMI routine jumped to by the <kbd>Restore</kbd> key did a check first whether the <kbd>Stop</kbd> key was being held and just returned otherwise.  Since this behavior could be changed, hacking on the <kbd>Restore</kbd> key alone could create some special reaction in some special cases (in some games, for instance).

Comment: Did the VIC-20 and Commodore PETs also have a `RESTORE` key and did it behave in the same way?

Comment: I never had a VIC-20, but I remember using it at a friend's and I have no different memories.  Also pictures show a `Restore` key like on the C64, but I still only can guess it was the same.  I had a PET once, but never used it, so there I also do not know, sorry.

Comment: The PET definitely did not have the `RESTORE` key or a Commodore key for that matter.

Comment: I had a Vic20 (but not a C64) and I remember RunStop + Restore being a "reset" key combination behaving as described in these answers. So safe to say that Vic20 and C64 had the same behaviour.

Comment: +1 for the first part about the `Restore` key. I used to have a C64 and I remember that weird behavior. It's nice to read an explanation for that after >30 years...

Comment: `RESTORE` key is special but it doesn't IMHO deserve to be called 'weird'. Its behaviour is also not 'unreliable' but 'well thought through'. The additional filter circuit prevents accidental triggering of an NMI. It requires deliberate action of stronger keystroke than other keys in order to trigger a potentially destructive to software processes, non-maskable interrupt. Also - some Commodore models don't have this circuit and on them `RESTORE` key behaves like all other keys and is as much mistype prone.

Comment: The circuit behind it makes the key work only (mostly) if pressing the key mechanically is done so hard that a chatter is the electric result.  The hardware of the keyboard isn't specially designed to create this, though.  In my opinion, the whole setup is a hack.  It works, but it stresses the hardware more than it was designed for.  Feel free not to call it weird, but I think that word expresses what I feel about this quite fine.

Comment: @Alfe: The hardware looks for a *brief* press.  There's no need to use a lot of force.

Comment: There is a hack that disables `Restore` key. First you set up a timer that fires interrupt on NMI line in a few cycles, then you continue your program through NMI vector. The trick is not to acknowledge an interrupt to that timer so that NMI hangs at logic 0 forever and `Restore` is no more functional.

Comment: @supercat Right, the hardware is looking for a brief press, and users are known (I've lived through the era, so I know first hand) to have created these by hacking with unusual amount of force on that key.  It might have been unnecessary; still most kids at the time would have told you that that's the way the `Restore` key was being used.

Comment: @Alfe: That was popular folklore at the time, but I don't think any version of the hardware actually required anything other than a brief press with normal force.

Comment: I seem to remember the Restore key was frequently the first one to break, as people would hammer it in frustration trying to get it to 'take'.

Answer (score 15):

I believe the C64 keys were carried over from the VIC-20.  The VIC-20 keys (somewhat at least) have some history from the PET series too.

Taken from [Wikipedia on the VIC 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_VIC-20):

> When they returned to California from that meeting, Tomczyk wrote a
>   30-page memo detailing recommendations for the new computer, and
>   presented it to  Tramiel. Recommendations included programmable
>   function keys (inspired by  competing Japanese computers),
>   full-size typewriter-style keys, and  built-in RS-232.

The keys you mentioned are mostly self-explaining.  <kbd>RUN/STOP</kbd> would run or halt an application and was programmable in software.  The fact that "RUN" rarely (if at all) started an application wasn't a limit of the key.

The <kbd>C=</kbd> key could be said to exist as mere corporate branding such as the "Apple" keys on the Apple II series.  Useful as a META key or "special" key to allow specific combinations in software.

I have to admit, I'm not sure of the history of the <kbd>Restore</kbd> key.

Also, keep in mind, that before the VIC-20 the biggest success Commodore had in computers was the PET.  The PET originally had terrible calculator keys that was quickly replaced by a real, full-travel keyboard.  Commodore seemed to learn their lesson in bad keyboards as many of their computers after the original PET actually had pretty good keyboards.  Even their cheaper models like the C16.  Of course, there are exceptions.

Finally, Tamiel was legendary in using parts he had on hand.  Which is one reason why the C64 inherited the VIC-20 keyboard.  So he wasn't going to design a completely new keyboard for the C64.

Comment: Last statement: Don't forget the C116.

Answer (score 3):

In order not to trigger the NMI with every contact bounce when hitting the Restore Key, there is a simple RC filter. The timing constant is marginal for the purpose, though. This is why the key has to be tapped and not just pressed down like any other. 
Back in the day there were some tutorials on which parts to exchange to make it behave normally.
As to why Commodore never changed the parts themselves, several stories made the rounds. Some of the people involved liked the behaviour, or others in the chain were too lazy to get the changes into production.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange! Please read the [tour] and [answer]. It'd be good if you edited your answer to state that the Restore key triggered a NMI at the beginning, and explain what that is; that'd make it more complete. ☺

Answer (score 3):

There are very good answers describing the functions of C64's special keys. But nobody mentioned the modern counterparts.

<kbd>C=</kbd> is a modifer key. It is used to bring additional PETSCII characters and also to change text color. Obviously, it has branding function, too. Modern counterparts can be <kbd>⌘</kbd> (Old Apple key) or Windows key.

<kbd>run/stop</kbd> Normal function of this key is to stop running program listings or basic programs. Modern counterpart is <kbd>ESC</kbd>. When used in combination with shift it loads the first program from datasette. There is no modern day counterpart of this function.

<kbd>Clr/Home</kbd> Home function is identical to modern keyboard Home button. ClR is same as CLS command in Dos console.

<kbd>Restore</kbd> button, also called as soft-reset, returns the computer into the initial opening state without clearing the memory. It is very useful debugging/or hacking tool. Not used much by the gamers as the key was mostly disabled by the game developers as the first step of copy protection efforts.

Hardware triggered soft-reset idea carried over to Amiga as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Amiga</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Amiga</kbd>. In some ways it can be seen as a variation of modern <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>